# Не могу нормально скачать исходники Android OS, хотелось бы узнать, как их просто просмотреть?

Tags: android

Ребят, как мне скачать исходники операционки Android без repo, а просто, грубо говоря, прямой ссылкой. Ну фиг с ссылкой, где их мне вообще взять, т.е хотябы просмотреть? Где можно без гемора посмотреть исходники? Я смотрел Git от Google, но там куча всего, но я так и не нашел свой android-7.0.0_r36

Answer (score 0):

Ясно, в общем я нашёл для себя такой вариант. Я просто скачал прошивку и разобрал её. Нужны следующие инструменты:
Android SDK
Android Kitchen - поможет с образами системных партиций.
JD-GUE - декомпилятор java кода. Говорят лучший в плане удобства
JD Java Decompiler - тоже декомпилятор, первый бывает не понимает код, этот может решить эту проблему, не совсем удобен
Smali - тоже декомпилятор, но уже для Dalvik кода smali.
Backsmali - обратный процесс компиляции
dex2jar - для конвертации исполняемых файлов Dalvik кода.

Список инструментов взят с сайта: https://m.habr.com/ru/post/181826/

Но я уверен, что есть ещё способы